# Substituting the value of a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

this might be a stupid question, but it's got me stumped

I have a varying number of text input forms on a webpage named user1, user2, user3, etc. I want to access the values of these forms in a javascript function to check the form input. Normally I'd do that via:

```
document.submitForm.user1.value
```

However, since I have the total number of fields stored in a variable, I'd like to go through all of the forms in a for loop.

```
for(i=1;i<=numFields;i++)
{
  var firstUser = document.submitForm.user[i].value
}
```

However I'm not sure how to substitute the value of i into the statement where I put the [i]. How would I go about doing that/is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. It seems fine, except that you are receiving all those text fields into one var `firstUser`. Is it not better to have an array for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `user1` property of `submitForm` can also be accessed with `submitForm['user1']`, which allows you to do this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= numFields; i++) {
  var firstUser = document.submitForm['user' + i].value;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What `.user[1]` means is: get the `user` property, and from that property get the `1` property.

Instead, you want a string concatenation to get e.g. the `user1` property out of `"user"` and `1`:

```
document.submitForm["user" + i].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

and heres a long way to do it :D

```
var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i in inp){
    if(inp[i].type == "text"){
        if(inp[i].name.substring(0,4) == 'user'){
            // Do your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because this dosent force him to know the number of those inputs :)